# PHP Mysql Query returns true, nothing changes in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a delete function for my application, which looks somewhat like the following:

```
$this->db->begin();
$sql .= "delete from ".MAIN_DB_PREFIX."places_contacts where fk_place = ".$this->db->escape($placeid)." and fk_contact = ".$this->db->escape($contactid);
$ressql = $this->db->query($sql);
            
if($ressql){
     $this->db->commit();
     if($delete == 1) return 1;
 }
 else{
       dol_syslog("Removing Contact went wrong: ".$this->db->lasterror, LOG_ERR);
       $error++;
       $this->db->rollback();
       if($delete == 1) return -2;
 }
```

This query works for me, when I paste the value of `$sql` into the terminal and just run it in mysql. `$ressql` is true after the query gets executed, the function also commits right after.
When debugging I can see that the `$affected_rows` goes to 1 from 0 after the query is executed.
Additionally, this problem only exists with trying to run a `delete` query, it works fine with `inser` and `update`.

I enabled mysql query logs, and the query is inside the query logs (not error log).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do SELECT right after this line `$this->db->commit();` and see what you get.

Comment: `if($delete == 1)` - Where do you define `$delete`? You also have `$sql .=` which suggests that you're adding this query onto something else? What does `$sql` contain before this? And why are you using transactions if you're only making one query?

Comment: I see `$sql .= "..."` which means you're appending the delete to some other value that was already in the `$sql` variable. What was that variable holding before this code?

Comment: Another thing, a query will only return `false` if it fails, which means on errors. If the query is valid, but didn't find a matching document to delete, it won't return `false`. So just because `if ($ressql)` passes, it doesn't mean that anything was actually deleted.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: @M.Eriksson $delete is a variable passed to the function, `$sql` is defined as an empty string above. This function either deletes or inserts. In this case it either links a contact person to a place or you can unlink it.

Comment: @shingo the select after the commit works

Comment: What does "works" mean? Did you get a record from the select query or not?

Comment: _"$delete is a variable passed to the function"_ - What function? Please show _all_ relevant code (like where the variables you're using is comming from). You also never answered the point of using transactions. You also never check if the queries actually did something or not, but only if the query didn't fail (because of some error)

Comment: The other code is not relevant. The SQL Query gets created as exactly as it should, I can copy paste it to my terminal and it will run & delete the row. I use transactions as it was standard practice in this project when I joined, so I did not change the way of doing it. I think it's because autocommit is disabled.

Comment: @M.Eriksson However now I removed the begin of the transaction and the commit and now it works. I am not that knowledgeable with transactions, I think I had a nested one or something which was causing the bug.

Comment: If you're only making one single query, then it doesn't make sense to use transactions. If the single query fails, no harm done. Transactions are used in cases you need to do multiple queries, where all queries needs to be successful. Then you can roll all back if one fails (within the same transaction)

Comment: Yeah I just read up on it. Thank you for the tip.